# Why will one code work but the other not with getting NSUserDefaults?

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

just want to know why one code work and the other one doesn't when retrieving a value from NSUserDefault

Here is how i save the info into nsuserdefaults:

```
let prefs = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
prefs.setValue(user_names, forKey: "username") //storing the username "test"
```

this is how i retrieve the nsuserdefaults info:

```
let prefs = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults() //preference name

let username1 = prefs.stringForKey("username") //doesn't work
let username2: [NSString]? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("username") as? [NSString] //works

print(username1) //doesn't work - "nil"
print(username2) //works - "test"
```

can someone explain to me why username1 doesn't work but username2 works? thanks

Comment: data type of user_names is?

Comment: @johnjay22113 So a `String`? Your code indicates that it's an array of strings, i.e `[String]`. You're trying to retrieve both an array of strings and a single string from the same key, therefore it's quite logical that only one of them could work – as the user defaults can either contain a `[String]` or `String` for a given key, it can't contain both.

Comment: In the case of `username` you're saving an array of strings, and trying to receive a string, ofcourse it won't work. `username2` works as you ask for an object with you later on convert to an array - the original data type you saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal way is the second way. This is how you should do it

```
 let myString = "Test"
 var myStringArray = ["Test"]
```

To save

```
 NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(myString, forKey: "Key")

 NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(myStringArray, forKey: "Key")
```

To get the value in a safe way (objectForKey may return nil if not set first time)

```
 NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Key") as? String ?? myString

 NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Key") as? [String] ?? myStringArray
```

You are checking if the object exists (as? ...) and if it does not you use the default values in your property (?? ...)

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html) you can only store :

> A default object must be a property list, that is, an instance of (or
>   for collections a combination of instances of): NSData, NSString,
>   NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. If you want to store any
>   other type of object, you should typically archive it to create an
>   instance of NSData.

So if you want to store object which have different type you have to do this :

```
let data  = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(yourObject)
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setObject(data, forKey:"yourObject" )
```

Then if you want to retrieve it :

```
if let data = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("yourObject") as? NSData
   {
    let yourObject = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as! YourObjectType

    }
```

Hope this will help you !

Comment: I want to store string. Am i doing it right with the code i used?

Comment: I posted an answer that should help you

Answer (score 0):

stringForKey returns an optional, so you can use the nil coalescing operator "??" to return an empty string "" in case of nil:

let username1 = prefs.stringForKey("username") ?? ""

Answer (score 0):

I tried Your Code and it works for me. You can check this in images
Code:-

```
let user_names = "test"
    let prefs = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    prefs.setValue(user_names, forKey: "username")
    let username1 = prefs.stringForKey("username")
    print(username1!)
```

OutPut Image:-

[image: OutPut Image]